# Horror webcomic about a sleepover where a girl is dared to kiss a boy but she's attacked by monsters in his room

Tags: story-identification, horror, webcomics

I stumbled on a YouTube short. The comic is about a girl sleepover playing truth or dare until it was a tall black haired girl's turn and she was dared to kiss the hostess' brother. She accepts it and goes to his room. When she gets there, a big giant monster appears and vomits blood on her and it launches her out to the door. The black haired girl warns the other that the monsters eat the girl's brother and run but the monsters killed the whole family and are slowly killing them one by one.

It turns out this was all a scary story told by the same black haired girl but it's revealed that something is connecting her to a closet.

Before you ask "Why not search in your YouTube history" I tried but I can't find it and also I lose track of time easily and it's hard to remember when I saw it. It might have been weeks ago or months

Comment: Why not search in your YouTube history?

Comment: I just say i can't this short dosen't have title so it just a guess at this point

Comment: @Valorum In my experience Youtube history search isn't very good unless you remember the exact title.

Comment: That the thing this horror short bearly title this comic it just said silent horror i thought that the title turn out i watch couple of silent horror with different artist also they don't leave link to this comics that why i don't know where it is